# Best way to store data using APDU's?

Tags: javacard, apdu, multiple-records

I have bunch of records in my offcard application and I want to save them all in javacard,
The question is:

- What is the best way of transferring data to Java Card?
- Should I transfer all data record by record (each one with a APDU) or send all the records in just one APDU?

Of course I know the limitation size of APDU and I'm using extended APDU in order to send all data just in one extended APDU which is more than 255  bytes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter much if you send your data in one extended length APDU or one single APDU security wise. It is however much better to send unrelated information using separate APDU's. This would make your application much more modular. Note that if you send related information using separate APDU's, you may need to keep state between those APDU's for validation purposes (e.g. you may have to send either none or all of them, or send the APDU's in specific order).

Furthermore, ISO 7816-4 only defines 2 byte status words to send back to the sender, e.g. `8A80` to indicate *any* error in the command data. This means that it is impossible to tell from the status word which of the records contains failure information.

Finally, there are certainly still readers and software out there that have issues handling extended length APDU's. So if your software is going to be used by other parties you may want to stick to normal length APDU's.

Comment: Thanks alot, Lets say It's a patient prescribe, header and body of a prescribe, what's your opinion now?

Comment: I would personally use separate APDU's. I'm using separate APDU's in my current product, using extended length in case e.g. a full wrapped key does not fit into an APDU.

Comment: By extended APDU I mean chaining, why a wrapped key should not fit into an extended APDU

Comment: I would not use the term "extended APDU" if you mean chaining, there is a bit of a difference between chaining and using extended length APDU's, and the term certainly hints at the latter. A wrapped key may not fit into an APDU if it is an asymmetric key, containing all parameters; e.g. a 2048 bit RSA key will never fit in 255 bytes.